# FTP Connection Refused (Using FTPZilla)

Tags: ftp, server

I have googled and searched all over but I am still having trouble getting connected to a site using the ftpzilla

I am getting this read out when I try to connect to the server using the network connection wizard

> Connecting to probe.filezilla-project.org
>
> Response: 220 FZ router and firewall tester ready
>
> USER FileZilla
>
> Response: 331 Give any password.
>
> PASS 3.9.0.6
>
> Response: 230 logged on.
>
> Checking for correct external IP address
>
> Retrieving external IP address from
>   http://ip.filezilla-project.org/ip.php
>
> Checking for correct external IP address IP 173.56.114.112
>   bhd-fg-bbe-bbc
>
> Response: 200 OK
>
> PREP 60010
>
> Response: 200 Using port 60010, data token 1063172065
>
> PORT 173,56,114,112,234,106
>
> Response: 200 PORT command successful
>
> LIST
>
> Response: 150 opening data connection
>
> Response: 503 Failure of data connection.
>
> Server sent unexpected reply.
>
> Connection closed

The weird thing is I only get this error for this particular server and the server I use for my personal site (namecheap.com) gives me no such error. Does anyone know why this may be happening? And please try not to point me to the network configuration wiki because I have read through that and I still am at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PORT 173,56,114,112,234,106
....  
Response: 503 Failure of data connection.
...
please try not to point me to the network configuration wiki
```

You are using active mode, that is the ftp client (FileZilla) waits for a connection from the server. Obviously the server can not connect to the client which indicates that something like a firewall restricts the connection.

Since according to your description this happens only with few servers, you either use only these servers with active mode or these servers are protected by firewalls which do not allow active mode. Have you tried with passive mode?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue connecting and made the following changes and had success.

Go to File>>>Site Manager>>>

For my site, I changed the Encryption to "Only use plain FTP(insecure)" and had success. May you find the same success.